# SKScene didChangeSize called twice when SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill is set

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am using SKScene's didChangeSize method to try to keep a node in the center of the scene when the scene is resize as follows:

```
-(void)didChangeSize:(CGSize)oldSize {
    CGPoint newPosition;
    newPosition.x = self.someNode.position.x + (self.size.width - oldSize.width)/2;
    newPosition.y = self.someNode.position.y + (self.size.height - oldSize.height)/2;
    self.someNode.position = newPosition;
}
```

The scene uses `scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill;`

However, when the scene's view changes size, such as on an orientation change, the scene's didChangeSize method is called twice (from `-[SKScene setSize:]` and `-[SKView layoutSubviews]`.  In addition, the `self.size` and `oldSize` are not updated between calls.

What would be the best way to ignore the second call?  Thanks.

**Update:**

As a solution, I am storing the screen size in an iVar (and using it as the "oldSize" in didChangeSize).  I then update the iVar manually at the end of the didChangeSize method. Thus, in the second didChangeSize call the "oldSize" (that I now get from the iVar) has already been changed.